# Can a device's automatic connection to Wifi be compromised with a duplicate SSID

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, wireless-access-point

I imagine that this is likely a pretty simple question to answer. I wanted to know if you have a wireless network with a password that your devices automatically connect to and a malicious actor creates another network with an identical SSID. Is there a possibility that your device automatically connects to that malicious network **thinking** that it's actually connecting to your legitimate network?

Comment: See if this answer helps you: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/137104/is-hacking-wi-fi-that-easy-just-spoof-and-its-hacked